# Magento + ShipSync Customs Value

Tags: php, magento

I am using the Magento ShipSync extension to easily create FedEx shipments from Magento:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/mage...dex-web-services-integration-for-magento.html

On the shipping labels it shows the total customs value. The problem is it shows the total in the currency used when the customer checked out. So if the customer buys a product costing £100 but checks out using USD it will show 163.11 instead of 100.00.

I think I have narrowed the problem down to the ship.php file and in particular line 461 i.e.:
$itemtotal += $item->getPrice();

You can see the entire file here:
http://pastebin.com/B5dwQKj8

Does anyone know how to make $itemtotal the total in the base currency and not the selected currency?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated ShipSync to the newest RateService WSDL (v14), and it offers a new "Preferred" rating method, which converts the currency to the store base currency; so I *think* that should fix your problem, since the actual Magento order is created during checkout.  Here's the latest build :

https://github.com/five23/shipsync-community/tree/shipsync-v5

It's still *very much* an alpha, and I've primarily been focusing on Rate requests and also bringing the app in line with all the changes in Magento 1.8, but I'll be turning my attention to the shipment creation functionality in the next few days, so definitely any feedback would be great.

Most honor,
David

Comment: I tried the latest version but the problem is still there.  The customs_value on the shipping label is still the amount in the currency used when checking out and not the base currency.  Still seems to be this code causing the problem $itemtotal += $item->getPrice(); in ship.php

Comment: Heya, thanks for the heads up on this..   Verified bug (added to the issue tracker on Github : https://github.com/five23/shipsync-community/issues/13).  I'll try to get this fixed ASAP